# Why might a canard aircraft suddenly pitch down from a level flight?

Tags: stability, canard

I have a canard aircraft which has pitch stability issues that I'm trying to troubleshoot.

The aircraft has a characteristic tendency to depart level flight in sudden dive/ or generate a massive nose-down pitch rate that inverts the aircraft after which the aircraft tumbles and recovery is not possible. It seems to be set off when the pilot tries to give nose-down commands. I cannot figure out if this is purely a CG placement issue or if something is wrong with my wing/canard geometry or incidence.

The canard has an area of 20% of the wing, the moment arm is 2.4 times the MAC of wing and horizontal tail volume is -0.467.

EDIT 1: aircraft geometry

[image]

All dimensions in mm.

Canard airfoil: SD7062 (4.5 deg incidence)
Wing airfoil: E1230 (0 deg incidence)

Control surface on canard runs throughout the span. Control surface chord is 35% of canard chord.

Canard is mounted higher than wing by 165mm.

Comment: I hope this is a simulation you are talking about. If so, could you show some plots?

Comment: Immediate first guess is that your canard is stalling.  However that does not match with the sign of the input.  Is this a flying model, a computer simulation, or what?  If it is a naive simulation, the developer may not have anticipated a canard and there may be an error in the physics model.

Comment: @U_flow Sadly its not a simulation, Its a 25 Kg aircraft for my masters project.

Comment: what happens when you command pitch-up?

Comment: @nielsnielsen Shows expected behaviour, Nothing abnormal.

Comment: How does it look like? Which airfoil have you used? Where is the CG? Do you have a picture? How do control surfaces look like? I suppose the canard geometry has to be tuned a bit, maybe a different airfoil or aspect ratio will be needed

Comment: The canard may be interfering with the aft wing enough to affect trim.  When pitch down command is given, AoA on canard reduces, and all of a sudden the aft wing has much more lift (from reduction of interference)(I think Langley had the same problem).  A picture of your design would be very helpful.

Comment: @Mridul, do you have a data recording device onboard?

Comment: I would try increasing the incidence of the canard surface in increments and trying out each increment. When you apply nose down elevator, the effective incidence of the surface is reduced as the chord line is angled downward by the trailing edge moving up. Possibly the ND down elevator is reducing canard AOA to zero or even negative at some amount of TE up displacement, which would explain the tuck under, which is the canard/wing seeking a trim state where both surfaces are lifting in the same direction.

Comment: @Mridul aside from checking control throws up and down, you may try mounting the canard higher or lower relative to the main wing to rule out interference effects.  What type of airfoil are you using for main wing and canard?

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni  Updated the aircraft geometry, I'm not at liberty to post real pictures of aircraft as yet

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni Can you give me a reference for langley's aircraft?

Comment: @JohnK That is what I think is happening as well. It seems to happen close to 4-5 deg on up deflection. I can't figure out once the tuck under happens why do my control surfaces stop responding? Also can't figure out a possible remedy for the issue

Comment: What happens with canard designs (unfortunately) is the fuselage can contribute to directional instability.  Here also the drag of the forward unit when control is applied would be contributory when the nose was pitched.  Try (temporarily) mounting a large tail on the back, essentially making it a tri-plane.  It may be a directional stability issue.  Rutan Vari-eze design may be a good reference.  Where is the engine mounted?

Comment: Aerodynamics characteristics of wing and [canard](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/362593331_Numerical_Investigation_of_SD7062_Airfoil_with_Single-Slotted_Flap_for_Different_Flight_Conditions_Progress_in_Computational_Fluid_Dynamics_An_International_Journal_-_accepted) look ok. Anyway according to [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274110103_Aerodynamic_Impact_of_Aspect_Ratio_at_Low_Reynolds_Number) SD7062 suffers from "*hysteresis loop at higher Reynolds numbers*". Have you done a rough longitudinal stability study? It might be that the CG is not enough forward.

Comment: @sophit that is similar to what John is saying.  I agree.